# Is there any method for insert ssh key in putty when i need to connect cisco router?

Tags: cisco, ssh, remote

I need to connect to cisco router and use private key to connect, but i need to use to putty for ssh. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Go to SSH -- AUTH here you browse and select your private KEY.

Regards,
Ganapareddy sudhakar

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used PuTTY in ages, but it used to have a SSH agent tool called `pageant`. It seems to be available on the PuTTY downloads page. See also the [PuTTY documentation.](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.73/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant)